# Double Array to Object Array?

Tags: c#, casting

I have following array:

```
double[] Series = new double[] { 7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6 }
```

Series debugging view :

```
> Series
--> [0]
--> [1]
--> ...
--> [10]
--> [11]
```

When I write following:

```
object[] object_array = new object[] { Series }
```

object_array debugging view : (more than one level)

```
> object_array
--> [0]
----> [0]
----> [1]
----> ...
----> [10]
----> [11]
```

I write following to prevent new level:

```
object[] object_array = new object[Series.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < Series.Length; i++)
{
    object_array[i] = Series[i];
}
```

This is the one of the other solutions. But I think, there may be a better way to do this. Is there a problem for me to use above loop? Or different way?

(I use highcharts. If I give array that contains more than one level, it does not work.)

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like it will still pass a double array if you pass object_array[0].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By doing this

```
object[] object_array = new object[] { Series }
```

you are assigning a double array as the first object item of the array object_array. You are actually creating 2D array with one row. You can use something like this:

```
double[] Series = new double[] { 7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6 };
object[] object_array = new object[Series.Length];
Series.CopyTo(object_array, 0);
```

Comment: @ErenErsönmez, I m sorry, I did syntax error. Your code is true, too.

Answer (score 8):

```
var object_array = Series.Cast<object>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

Use LINQ:

```
double[] series = new double[] { 7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6 };
object[] seriesAsAbjectArray = series.Cast<object>().ToArray();
```

The reason why you **cannot** just cast it to an `object[]`, is that `double` is a value type, and therefore you have to create a new array containing the *boxed* `double`-items.

Answer (score -2):

You just assign it, because `double` is an `object`.

```
object[] object_array = Series;
```

Comment: I get an error when I try that:  'Cannot implicitly convert type 'double[]' to 'object[]''

Comment: This just hides the fact that it's a double array, instead of changing it to an object array.