# Why doesn't "object[]" work?

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I thought object meant all data types but for some reason it doesn't work.

I made a `ToStringArray` method which converts a array of any kind to a string array, `string[]`, i wrote it like this, sins it converts any kind:

```
public static string[] ToStringArray(this object[] buffer)
{
//code here.
}
```

But the issue is, if i have a array like:

```
byte[] x = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

and then try to do:

```
string[] s = x.ToStringArray();
```

I get a error which says `byte[] does not contain the definition ToStringArray`.

How do i fix this or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361298/double-array-to-object-array

Answer (score 6):

There isn't an *implicit* conversion between them, and the array variance trick only works for arrays of reference types; `byte[]` doesn't qualify for this.

You probably want to use generics instead:

```
public static string[] ToStringArray<T>(this T[] buffer)
{
//code here.
}
```

Comment: @CodingYoshi an array of one reference-type can be treated as an array of another reference-type if there is a reference-preserving conversion available between them; most commonly, this means that `object[]` is interchangeable with any `SomeClass[]` via a cast. This is unusual, because this isn't a reliable conversion - you can't but a `DbConnection` into a `SomeClass[]` just because you thought it was an `object[]`. For *generics*, the `in` / `out` variance formalizes *safe* rules for this.